# Multiple interface containing a method with same signature

Tags: java, oop, interface

A class can implement multiple interface in Java, if some of the interfaces contain methods with same signature. Since a class can implement a method with a given signature only once. what problems can this situation lead to ?

```
 interface a {
    public show();
}
interface b {
    public show();
}

class name implements a,b {
    private int var = 10;
    public show() {
    System.out.print(var);
 }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be a problem if you want different implementations.

Comment: None, as long as the implementation for both is the same.

Comment: This has been asked many times before, and in previous questions, the code displayed was valid Java.

Answer (score 2):

No problems. Single implementation works for the both interfaces in derived class.

But if you want different implementations for each interfaces, you need to change the signature.